# json parsing error when extracting a part of a json object

Tags: json, node.js, postgresql, backbone.js

I'm trying to insert a json object into a column called data of type json in my postgres database using node.js.

The data I receive from the client (backbone) is of this format:

```
{id: someid, questions: [{some question data}, {some more question data}]}
```

If I insert the whole of the data (req.body), it works fine. end of story.

However, in my case I only want to insert the array of questions (req.body.questions).

And this does not work.
When I parse req.body.questions, I get false returned (not json).

However, if I manually insert the data I get into postgres, it works.
This is an example of the data for reference:

```
[ { completed: true,
        score: 1,
        answerList: [ '1' ],
        choicesNumber: 4,
        QuestionId: 6,
        startTime: '2016-01-19T22:09:47.090Z',
        clickNb: 1,
        endTime: '2016-01-19T22:09:51.491Z' },
      { completed: true,
        score: 1,
        answerList: [ '1' ],
        choicesNumber: 4,
        QuestionId: 5,
        startTime: '2016-01-19T22:09:52.209Z',
        clickNb: 1,
        endTime: '2016-01-19T22:09:53.713Z' }
    ]
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

> error inserting experience { [error: invalid input syntax for type json]
>     name: 'error',
>     length: 195,
>     severity: 'ERROR',
>     code: '22P02',
>   ...
>
> detail: 'Expected ":", but found ",".',
>
> ...
>
> where: 'JSON data, line 1: ...b\":1,\"endTime\":\"2016-01-19T22:09:51.491Z\"}",...',
>
> ...
>
> file: 'json.c',
>     line: '1184',
>     routine: 'report_parse_error' }

I guess I'm missing something pretty obvious, but I'm tearing my hear apart on this problem!

Comment: Just shooting in the dark here :) Are you [parsing the body](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)? Maybe it works with just the body, because it's a string?

Comment: Have you tried inserting the json as string... eg `JSON.stringify(obj)`?

Comment: it looks like you're not the first person to encounter this issue.  assuming you're using the `pg` library see: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/865

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pgClient.query('INSERT INTO my_table (my_json_column) VALUES ($1)', [JSON.stringify(myArrayObj)], cb)
```

Comment: JSON.stringify does the job it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the expression "req.body.questions" only returns the array object which is not a valid JSON.

Try creating a temporary JSON such that temJSON = {qInfo:req.body.questions}

Then pass the temporary JSON to store into DB.

Hope this helps.
-Nith

-- ps --

Note the error statement as it says colon character is missing in the input where it expects something like `<KEY>:<VALUE_OBJ>`